# understanding the modulus operator in javascript

Tags: javascript

Twenty modulus six is equal to two, which is the remainder but how to know the the modulus is using the 3 to perform the operation?

`20 % 6 = 2`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: If one of the answers submitted below solved your problem, could you accept that one?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Math.floor(20 / 6);
```

for this. It rounds down so you have the largest number possible without decimals.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the quotient, you just have to truncate the division

```
Math.trunc(20/6) //Return 3
```

[Reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)

Answer (score 0):

Modulus is *not* using the `3`, it simply knows that:

```
   20 / 6 = 3, with a remainder of 2
=> 20 % 6 = 2
```

If you want the `3`, you just need the expression:

```
Math.floor(20 / 6)
```

(or possibly `Math.trunc` depending on how you want negative numbers handled - `floor` rounds towards negative infinity, `trunc` rounds toward zero).